# PostMessage Mouse click is worked but without moving

Tags: c#, macros, client, mouse, postmessage

I want to simulate a mouse click on a specific application with C# 'PostMessage' function.

The click worked well, but the mouse position was not send.

Perhaps it is updating the mouse position in real time in the application.

Although the use of the SetCursorPos function change the cursor, the actual mouse judgment has not changed.

How can you change the position of the mouse in the application with 'PostMessage'?

Comment: please tell us what type of application this is

Comment: Game program that has game guard.

Comment: define 'Program` - ie, web, wpf, windows, uwp etc etc..

Comment: umm, Probably 'wpf'

Comment: ok, get back to us when decided - good luck

Comment: You mean the program that doesn't work properly with PostMessage? Or My Project? the latter is Winform.

Comment: do you want mouse position screen or inside application (with handle)? and what do you mean by "the actual mouse judgment has not changed."

Comment: Literally.
When pointing to item number 1, if you point to item number 2, the cursor position shown is above item number 2, but it shows option of item number 1.

Comment: If you change the tap, you can normally point to item number 2.